# Flow unable to infer union type with computed object keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, flowtype

So I have a union type, EduType, defined as follows:

```
export type EduType =
  | { level: string }
  | { program: string }
  | { level: string, program: string }
```

and a function that returns a function which expects an `EduType`, defined as follows

```
updateEduSelects(which: 'level' | 'program') {
  return (_, __, val: string) => {
    const value = val != null ? val : ''; //if val is null replace with ''
    const newEdu = value === 'None'       //if None entered, both fields should
      ? { level: 'None', program: 'None' }//be none
      : { [which]: value };
    this.props.onNewClientEdu(newEdu); 
  };
}
```

My problem is that flow errors on the line `this.props.onNewClientEdu(newEdu)`, saying `object literal. Could not decide which case to select`. When I had two functions and no computed key value it works fine. My gut says that I'm typing the `EduType` object wrong, but I'm still new-sh to flow and not sure how to represent it better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldnt you do `{ level?: string, program?: string}` and just leaving it empty instead of that `"None"` value? (Just a hint, and i actually dont know flow, just guessing)

Comment: You could do that, but then any time I wanted to use a value in that object you'd have to do a null check. It's the next best option if I can't find another way to represent this.

Comment: I think `if(type.level)` is much better than `if(type.level !== "None")`. And you dont need to check for `null` always, in most cases it will work without such checks.